# Help Required to overcome SharePoint Online External Email limitations

Tags: sharepoint-online, asp.net, powerapps-canvas

We need a help on sending emails with attachments from SharePoint online.

We have a powerapp Canvas application in sharepoint online which will allow us to trigger external emails. We are using outlook connector to trigger such emails.

Now, The business ask is to use sharedmailbox(for e.g NoReply@domain.com) to trigger external emails. we have tried using powerautomate but we have limitation with premium connector.

**Problem Statement:** More than 1000 External Emails can be triggered in a minute and may be it increases/decreases on every minute. Daily limit we cannot predict.

what is the best approach to achieve this.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/external-sharing-overview